# How to read results from startActivityForResults

Tags: java, android

Team

My question is, how do I read the result from the `startAtcivityForResult`.
When the button is pressed, it calls `bStock()`, which makes a URL call and retrieves data. I have verified the URL call is correct and that I do get data.
I have used `finishActivity(1)` to not display the actual content or result. For the sake of this message here is what I get when not using `finishActivity(1)`

[image]

My goal is to read the result and only display certain values like name and last price. Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

    final Button buttonStock = findViewById(R.id.buttonS);
    buttonStock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
              bStock();
        }
    });
}

static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

protected void bStock() {
    String url = "http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp?symbol=AG";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    i.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
    startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
    finishActivity(1);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        //if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) { // 0 -1
        // Get the URI that points to the selected contact
        Uri o = data.getData();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Name ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();});
  }
}
```

I am using a `Toast` (for now) just to display the name, but I do not know how to read data. Any help would be appreciated.

Jesse

Answer (score 1):

That does not work as you expect, because the activity you are trying to start (chrome browser) is not prepared to return the result you want, to you. The intent (VIEW) tells the browser, to do just that -- view the given URL.

For activities that are not your own, you have to carecully check their description to see if they support any calls for results, and how they return it -- e.g. there is a 'take a picture'  intent, that will return the picture taken to you via some uri data.

Most of the time, startActivityForResult is used to start your own activities, which you want to return data to the calling activity. In that case, you can define yourself, on how to pass the results back to the calling activity.

Answer (score 1):

you may need to iterate through a cursor

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request it is that we're responding to
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Get the URI that points to the selected contact
            Uri contactUri = data.getData();
            // We only need the NUMBER column, because there will be only one row in the result
            String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER};

            // Perform the query on the contact to get the NUMBER column
            // We don't need a selection or sort order (there's only one result for the given URI)
            // CAUTION: The query() method should be called from a separate thread to avoid blocking
            // your app's UI thread. (For simplicity of the sample, this code doesn't do that.)
            // Consider using CursorLoader to perform the query.
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                    .query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            // Retrieve the phone number from the NUMBER column
            int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
            String number = cursor.getString(column);

            // Do something with the phone number...
        }
    }
}
```